# Create Excel from a xml file

Tags: xml, excel

I'm given a requirement to generate a **.xlsx** to get downloaded, when ever certain event is triggered.

I've developed it fully with **POI** using **XSSF** , but my problem is,
 it is taking too long to create the file and then to download.

After lot of search i found that there is a way to create a .XLSX file from XML but i don know how to go about it since i'm new to XML. Anyone who have crossed such a requirement or have knowledge on this, it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance for the reply.